# How does Google Maps V3 API manage the Z-Index of polygons?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have two polygons: `big` and `small` - **the small one is contained inside of the big one.**

Whether I execute:

```
//show big, then small...
big.setMap(null);
big.setMap(map);
small.setMap(null);
small.setMap(map);
```

Or I execute:

```
//show small, then big...
small.setMap(null);
small.setMap(map);
big.setMap(null);
big.setMap(map);
```

**I always end up with the big polygon on-top.** This means, I can't receive mouse events on the small polygon because it's hidden by the big polygon.

How does Google Maps V3 API manage the Z-Index of polygons? I'm thinking I'm going to have to drill a hole through the bigger polygon to let the smaller one shine through... but I'd rather not if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears there is no particular managment of the zIndex, similar to elements in a HTML-document the order of the elements inside the document that define the polygons will affect the behaviour, when you use multiple polygons without setting the zIndex the polygons created later will appear above the existing polygons.

The implemented solution to override this behaviour is to set  the zIndex-property of the polygons, give `small` a higher `zIndex` than `big`

Comment: I knew there was a better solution than cutting holes -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are your polygons fully opaque, or do they have some transparency?

If they are opaque, you can use the `zIndex` on the `Polygon` object as Dr. Molle points out.

If they are partially transparent, that may not give the effect you want - unless you do want the polygon fill colors to be alpha blended.

If you don't want the fill colors to blend, then you would indeed need to cut a hole in the larger polygon. This is really pretty simple, though. You just need to add a second ring to the larger polygon, and give it the same coordinates as the smaller polygon, but with the order of the coordinates reversed. You can copy an array and reverse the copy with:

```
var reversed = [].concat(array).reverse();
```

Here's an example of a [polygon with a hole in it](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/pentagon.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. The polygons are indeed semi-transparent, but I can live with the alpha-blend effect for now. Thanks for your help!